# monacaでkrpanoコンテンツをapp化しようとしています

Tags: monaca

monacaでkrpanoベースのコンテンツをapp化しようとしています。
monacaクラウドIDEのプレビューでは実行できますが、スマホ(アンドロイド4.2.2)のデバッグツールやデバッグビルドでは「ERROR:HTML5 Version not available!」となります。
HTMLで作成している段階にもローカルのファイルをブラウザでみようとしても同様のエラーがでるので、LAN内に簡易サーバーをたてて作業していましたが、同様の原因ではないかと思っています。
回避するための設定が必要なのではないかと思いますが、ご存知の方がいれば教えていただけないでしょうか。